# Mobile safari 9537.53 video tag crash

Tags: iphone, crash, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have an issue when trying and playing sources on Mobile Safari.

When I am doing the actual source switch from mp4 file to mp4 file safari crashes:

```
vid.src = src;
```

Do you know something about this issue?

Thanks,

Eliza